# Bug in variadic function template specialization with MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, variadic-templates

Using the Visual Studio Nov 2012 CTP, which supports variadic templates (among other things). The following code:

```
template<int, typename... Args>
void myfunc(Args... args)
{
}

template<>
void myfunc<1, float>(float)
{
}
```

produces the following errors:

```
error C2785: 'void myfunc(Args...)' and 'void myfunc(float)' have different return types
```

```
error C2912: explicit specialization 'void myfunc(float)' is not a specialization of a function template
```

(yeah, the first one is pretty funny)

So my questions are:

1) Am I writing legal C++11 here?

2) If yes, is there a way to find out if this is a known bug in MSVC before submitting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is perfectly legitimate code; both gcc-4.7.2 and clang 3.0 accept it.
2. Try searching [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).